# Set Airflow data interval to cover the previous month

Tags: airflow

**How to set the Airflow data interval to start at the start of the previous month and to end on the end of the previous month?**

Let's suppose that I have an ETL process that is executed at 8:00 a.m. on the 7th day of each month. I want to transform new data that were inserted between the start and end of the previous month.

So:

- on March 7th I want to process the data that arrived between Feb 1 and Feb 28 (or 29),
- on April 7th I want to process the data that arrived between Mar 1 and Mar 31,
- etc.

Unfortunately, I haven't found the way to "shift" the data interval so that it starts on the first and ends on the last day of the previous month.
Currently, if I execute the DAG, I will get following the period:

- for March 7th: 2023-02-07 8:00 a.m. - 2023-03-03 8:00 a.m.

```py
from __future__ import annotations
from datetime import datetime
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator
from airflow.timetables.interval import CronDataIntervalTimetable

##############


def do_the_etl(start_date_str: str, end_date_str: str) -> None:
    """
    in reality this executes a lenghty etl process,
    here just print a message
    """

    start_date = datetime.fromisoformat(start_date_str)
    end_date = datetime.fromisoformat(end_date_str)

    print(f"[Fake ETL] Querying for the period {start_date}-{end_date}")


####

ETL_DATE_START = "{{ data_interval_start }}"
ETL_DATE_END = "{{ data_interval_end }}"

##############

with DAG(
    dag_id="etl_test",
    start_date=datetime(2023, 2, 4),
    schedule_interval=CronDataIntervalTimetable(cron="0 8 7 * *", timezone="Etc/UTC"),
    catchup=False,
) as dag:
    run_etl = PythonOperator(
        task_id="etl",
        python_callable=do_the_etl,
        op_kwargs={
            "start_date_str": ETL_DATE_START,
            "end_date_str": ETL_DATE_END,
        },
    )

    run_etl
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `relativedelta` to modify the date.

```
# interval_start
{{ data_interval_end + macros.dateutil.relativedelta.relativedelta(months=-1, day=1) }}
# interval_end
{{ data_interval_end + macros.dateutil.relativedelta.relativedelta(months=-1, day=31) }}
```

`months=-1` means subtracting one month from the date.

`day=1` means setting the day of the date as `1`. Note it's not `days`.

`day=31` means setting the day of the date as the last day regardless of number of days in the month.